# Android - SurfaceView (width, height) (another) problem

Tags: android, surfaceview, screen-resolution

I develop Android apk with Android Studio and my application is mainly composed of a SurfaceView with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN visibility parameter.

On the `surfaceChanged()` event I read and save the width and height of this surface.
What I don't understand is that, on a RK3288 based board, using the same HDMI output screen resolution of 1280x720,
I have two different widths and heights depending the Android ROM version.

With Android 4.4 -> I read the same Surface `width` and `height` as the actual screen resolution (1280x720)
With Android 5.1 -> I read `width = 1920`, `height = 1080`, which doesn't respect the 1280x720 physical screen resolution.

In both cases what I draw using the width and height falls on the corresponding screen surface. My problem is that I use a BitMap for a 360° panorama display and FPS performance is completely bad in Android 5.1 while it is perfect in Android 4.4. (as the number of pixels to "move" is bigger).

In summary: why does a SurfaceView configured with the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN parameter not have the same resolution (draw surface) as the physical output HDMI resolution? Which parameters can affect this?

(PS: HDMI output mode is confirmed by the TV to be in 720p in both situations).

Many thanks ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HDMI Screen resolution issue while displaying android content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525870/hdmi-screen-resolution-issue-while-displaying-android-content)

Comment: No in fact it is the reverse case ... HDMI output is 1280x720 but "canvas" of SurfaceView is 1920x1080 ... (in the case of Android 5.1 version).